# Parsing csv and plotting within class structure

Tags: python, class, csv, matplotlib

Im trying to read out a CSV that contains a bunch of data from a tube furnace, and to plot the data so we can tune the furnace better - how can I use matplotlib on the variables im defining, is this the correct way to define, and how should I print my variables so I can see what im working with

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class CVD:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [genfromtxt('/Users/Derek/Desktop/DM041352.txt', delimiter=",", skip_header=4)] 
        self.time = self.data[:,0]
        self.sp1 = self.data[:,1]
        self.sp2 = self.data[:,2]
        self.sp3 = self.data[:,3]
        self.temp1 = self.data[:,4]
        self.temp2 = self.data[:,5]
        self.temp3 = self.data[:,6]
        self.mf1 = self.data[:,7]
        self.mf2 = self.data[:,8]
        self.mf3 = self.data[:,9]
        self.textsp = self.data[:,10]
        self.text = self.data[:,11]
        self.itemList=['Time','Set Point 1','Set Point 2','Set Point 3',
            'Temp 1', 'Temp 2', 'Temp 3', 'Mass Flow A', 'Mass Flow B',
            'Mass Flow C', 'T Ext SP', 'T Ext']
        print(self.text)
```